# auth_backend_http not installed on Rabbit MQ Docker Image 3.7.6

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am running `rabbitmq:3.7.6` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/) and have the following `rabbitmq.conf` file:

```
auth_backends.1         = http
auth_http.user_path     = http://1.2.3.4/api/rmq/user
auth_http.vhost_path    = http://1.2.3.4/api/rmq/vhost
auth_http.resource_path = http://1.2.3.4/api/rmq/resource
auth_http.topic_path    = http://1.2.3.4/api/rmq/topic
```

When I run the server, it crashes with the error below, leading me to believe `auth_backend_http` is not installed, even though the docs say it comes with RabbitMQ by default now.

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Config file generation failed 16:11:41.266 [error] You've tried to set auth_http.user_path, but there is no setting with that name.
16:11:41.266 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
16:11:41.279 [error]     ssl_options.depth
16:11:41.279 [error]     auth_backends.$num
16:11:41.279 [error]     auth_mechanisms.$name
16:11:41.279 [error] You've tried to set auth_http.vhost_path, but there is no setting with that name.
16:11:41.279 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
16:11:41.292 [error]     auth_backends.$num
16:11:41.292 [error]     auth_mechanisms.$name
16:11:41.292 [error]     default_vhost
16:11:41.292 [error] You've tried to set auth_http.resource_path, but there is no setting with that name.
16:11:41.292 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
16:11:41.307 [error]     auth_backends.$num.authn
16:11:41.307 [error]     auth_backends.$num.authz
16:11:41.307 [error]     auth_mechanisms.$name
16:11:41.307 [error] You've tried to set auth_http.topic_path, but there is no setting with that name.
16:11:41.307 [error]   Did you mean one of these?
16:11:41.319 [error]     auth_backends.$num
16:11:41.319 [error]     auth_mechanisms.$name
16:11:41.319 [error]     net_ticktime
16:11:41.319 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
16:11:41.319 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: auth_http.topic_path
16:11:41.319 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: auth_http.resource_path
16:11:41.320 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: auth_http.vhost_path
16:11:41.320 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: auth_http.user_path
```

**EDIT**: When I `RUN ls /plugins` I get the following:

```
README
...
rabbitmq_auth_backend_cache-3.7.6.ez
rabbitmq_auth_backend_http-3.7.6.ez
rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap-3.7.6.ez
rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl-3.7.6.ez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_auth_backend_http
```